# How to start activity with previous changes made by the user?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, start-activity

I have a listview of alarms that is created by the user in another activity. How do I click on these listview items and go to the specific activity with the previous changes that the user made? For example, the user selects item 2 in the listview of Activity A, this action should send the user to Activity B with the specific changes for item 2. It should have changes to the alarm time of say 8:00 AM and which days they chose.

Right now I am saving the data to a database with COLUMN, TIME, etc...

Each time they click on the listview, do I need to go to the database and grab the preferences they previously chose for that specific alarm, and manually make the changes to that Alarm Activity to mimic what they had before? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: i m still unclear with question

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data to persist, then you need to use a database, shared preferences, or other persistent store mechanism.

If you just need to transmit the choice to the other activity, you can add extra data to the intent that you use to start the second activity. For instance, in activity A:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("choice", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in activity B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int choice = intent.getIntExtra("choice");
    . . .
}
```

You can combine these, of course: persist the choice in a database and also send the choice as extra data in the intent (to save activity B the trouble of looking up the choice).

Comment: So if I need to grab the data for the selected alarm in the database, do I manually set each UI component with that data to open the activity to look like it was when saved?

Comment: @worm - I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish. If you have persistent data to save and restore, then the code that needs to use it (to initialize UI elements or whatever) needs to read it. The code that makes changes to the data needs to store it. If you have transient data (that doesn't need to be stored), then the source of the data needs to communicate it somehow to the code that needs to use it. This can also be by persistent store or, as I suggested, by direct communication through the intent. The details depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have persistent data that I need to save and restore. For example, the stock android alarm clock.. we make changes to each alarm preference and save that alarm, then if we want to go back and edit that specific alarm, we can click on that listview item and see the previous preferences that we had saved. What is the best way to go about that?